# Query a list of objects in each database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a list of about 300 Views spread out across several databases.

Some of the tables used in the DDL of the views have been dropped or renamed.

What I want to do is try to query all 300 views in each database.

If a query is successful, I want to output "Query Successful".
If a query fails because the object the view DDL is based on fails, I want to output "Query Failed".

The final output will look something like this

```
database_name     schema_name     view_name     status
db_1              dbo             view_1        Query Successful
db_2              abc             view_2        Query Failed
```

I know part of the solution will use the `sp_MSforeachdb` stored procedure, but I'm not sure what to do after that.

I have a list of all the objects I want to query stored in a table

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to list all views against all databases.
It will populate everything inside of #Result. After that, you can use your list to do joins and check whatever status you want.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Result') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Result;
CREATE TABLE #Result
([Database] VARCHAR(100), [schema_name] VARCHAR(100), [view_name] VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @DB SYSNAME,@cmd NVARCHAR(4000)

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @cmd = ''

SELECT TOP 1 @DB = D.name
FROM master..sysdatabases AS D
WHERE dbid > 4
    and DATABASEPROPERTYEX(D.name, 'status') = 'ONLINE'
ORDER BY D.name;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
      SET @cmd = 'USE ' + @DB + ';
            INSERT INTO #Result
            SELECT  DISTINCT ''' + @DB + ''' AS CustomerNumber ,sh.name, o.name AS ObjectName
            FROM sys.objects o 
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas sh on o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
            WHERE o.type = ''V''

    ';
      EXEC (@cmd)

      SELECT TOP 1 @DB = NAME
      FROM master..sysdatabases AS D
        WHERE dbid > 4
        AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(D.name, 'status') = 'ONLINE'
            AND D.NAME > @DB
      ORDER BY D.name
END

SELECT * FROM #Result R
```

Comment: This is a good start to get your list. Next you will have to validate each view. Instead SELECTING * from all them, like mentioned above. I would cycle through them with `EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule (view name)` and capturing a success or failure in a TRY\CATCH block that you use to write an update to your temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Excel, do the following:

Create 1 column with the words `Select Count(*) from` .
In a column off to the far right (make it the last column), use the `CONCATENATE` function to concatenate column 1 and the view name for each row

Final result will look something like this

```
A                             B             C
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM          view_1        =concatenate(A1, B1, ';')
                                            GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM          view_2        =concatenate(A3, B3, ';')
                                            GO
```

Then copy and paste everything from `column C` into SSMS.

Problem solved, I'm amazing, I know.

**Edit #1**:

Using count(*) is expensive, switched it to `select top 1`.

Comment: I would advise against this, as COUNT(*) could potentially cause a lot of reads. 
Perhaps something like `SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM ` would be similar in nature, but possibly less read intensive.

Comment: Way ahead of you, that' swhat I switched it to after I ran into that problem :)